# jpa query error "Unknown label Possible value " for a GET request

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a many to many relationship Songs and Artists. I try to write a method in repository to get songs together with artist (just his name). In the DBeaver, the query works but when I make a request in postman I get

```
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Unable to find column position by name: name",
```

Artist.java entity

```
package com.spotify.spotify.model;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Artist {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "cnp", nullable = false)
    private String cnp;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "active")
    private Boolean active;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
    fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "SongAlbumArtist",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cnp"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "song_album_id", name = "song_id")
    )
    //@JsonBackReference(value = "artistList")
    List<SongAlbum> songAlbumList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Artist() {
    }

    public Artist(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCnp() {
        return cnp;
    }

    public void setCnp(String cnp) {
        this.cnp = cnp;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Boolean getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(Boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public List<SongAlbum> getSongAlbumList() {
        return songAlbumList;
    }

    public void registerSong(SongAlbum songAlbum) {
        songAlbumList.add(songAlbum);
        songAlbum.getArtistList().add(this);
    }

    public void removeSong(SongAlbum songAlbum) {
        songAlbumList.remove(songAlbum);
        songAlbum.getArtistList().remove(this);
    }

    public void setSongAlbumList(List<SongAlbum> songAlbumList) {
        this.songAlbumList = songAlbumList;
    }
}
```

SongAlbum.java entity

```
package com.spotify.spotify.model;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.springframework.hateoas.RepresentationModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


@Entity
public class SongAlbum extends RepresentationModel<SongAlbum> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "song_album_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "genre")
    private EGenre genre;
    @Column(name = "year")
    private int year;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "type")
    private EType type;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "songAlbumList", fetch =FetchType.EAGER)
    //@JsonIgnore
    List<Artist> artistList = new ArrayList<>();

    public SongAlbum() {
    }

    public SongAlbum(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public SongAlbum(String name, EGenre genre, int year, EType type, List<Artist> artistList) {
        this.name = name;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.year = year;
        this.type = type;
        this.artistList = artistList;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public EGenre getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(EGenre genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public EType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(EType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public List<Artist> getArtistList() {
        return artistList;
    }

    public void setArtistList(List<Artist> artistList) {
        this.artistList = artistList;
    }

    public void registerArtist(Artist artist) {
        artistList.add(artist);
        artist.getSongAlbumList().add(this);
    }
}
```

SongAlbumRepository.java

```
package com.spotify.spotify.repository;

import com.spotify.spotify.dto.PostSongAlbumDTO;
import com.spotify.spotify.model.SongAlbum;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface SongAlbumRepository extends CrudRepository<SongAlbum, Integer> {

    @Query(value= "select song_album.song_album_id, song_album.genre, song_album.`type`, song_album.`year` from song_album_artist join artist on song_album_artist.cnp = artist.cnp join song_album on song_album_artist.song_id = song_album.song_album_id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<SongAlbum> findSongsWithArtists();

}
```

Song controller (just the get method)

```
    @GetMapping("/songs")
    public List<SongAlbum> test() {
        return songService.findSongArtist();
    }
```

Song service

```
    public List<SongAlbum> findSongArtist() {
        return songAlbumRepository.findSongsWithArtists();
    }
```

I get the error in console

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown label 'name'. Possible value [song_album.genre, year, genre, song_album.year, type, song_album.song_album_id, song_album.type, song_album_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues with your code.

1. In the query you are not returning the artist name. So it's throwing an error that the name column is not found. As you have a `ManyToMany` relationship it will also fetch the artist as you used `nativeQuery=true` it will not do another query to fetch the artist. Update your `SongAlbumRepository` with the following code/query.

```
@Repository
public interface SongAlbumRepository extends CrudRepository<SongAlbum, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "select song_album.song_album_id, song_album.genre, song_album.`type`, song_album.`year`, artist.name from song_album_artist join artist on song_album_artist.cnp = artist.cnp join song_album on song_album_artist.song_id = song_album.song_album_id",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<SongAlbum> findSongsWithArtists();

}
```

Added `artist.name` in select query.

2. You should use DTO objects instead of exposing Entity from the controller. Following are the scenario you can consider for your design.

- If you using ManyToMany, ManyToOne, and OneToOne mapping then you must skip bidirectional mapping. If you have then while converting the entity to JSON it will go in a circular loop and will never come back.
- Using mapping requires the hibernate session to be open until it converts the entity to JSON.
- With Entity expose it will also expose all and other related information which is not required. Which can lead to Penetration Test to be failed for your application.
- To partially save data you still need to pass the full object else it will reset other properties to null.

In the above code to make it work without DTO, you should use `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference`. Add `@JsonBackReference` in the Artist class and add `@JsonManagedReference` in the SongAlbum class.

Better to use DTOs.